# error: no matching function for call to 'es_queue::set_rpc_vector(std::vector >&, std::__cxx11::string)'

Tags: c++

In c++ I am trying to perform this function, but I am getting the error below.  I have not modified this code, or any other...I am just porting this to c++11 from C++98 and also I have upgraded boost to 1.66.

Error(s) seen:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'es_queue::set_rpc_vector(std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<rpcbasic_base> >&, std::__cxx11::string)'
event_queue->set_rpc_vector(d_rpc_vars, alias());

note: candidate: 'void es_queue::set_rpc_vector(std::vector<boost::any>&, const string&)'

void set_rpc_vector(std::vector<boost::any> &v, const std::string &alias);

note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<rpcbasic_base> >' to 'std::vector<boost::any>&'
            void set_rpc_vector(std::vector<boost::any> &v, const std::string &alias);
```

C++ Code name: es_queue.cc

```
es_sink::es_sink (
gr_vector_int insig,
int _n_threads,
int _sample_history_in_kilosamples,
enum es_queue_early_behaviors eb,
enum es_search_behaviors sb)
  : gr::sync_block (
      "es_sink",
      es_make_io_signature(insig.size(), insig),
      gr::io_signature::make (MIN_OUT, MAX_OUT, 0)),
      n_threads(_n_threads),
      sample_history_in_kilosamples(_sample_history_in_kilosamples),
      qq(100), dq(100),
      d_avg_ratio(tag::rolling_window::window_size=50),
      d_avg_thread_utilization(tag::rolling_window::window_size=50),
      d_avg_stall_percentage(tag::rolling_window::window_size=50),
      latest_tags(pmt::make_dict()),
      d_search_behavior(sb), d_stopping(false), stall_count(0)
{
    event_acceptor_setup(eb, sb, n_threads);

    d_time = 0;
    d_history = 1024*sample_history_in_kilosamples;
    set_history(d_history);

    // message port that tracks the production rate
    // for upstream schedulers
    message_port_register_out(pmt::mp("nconsumed"));
    message_port_register_out(pmt::mp("pdu_event"));
    message_port_register_out(pmt::mp("eb_discard"));

    // set up our special pdu handler
    event_queue->register_event_type("pdu_event");
    event_queue->bind_handler("pdu_event", this);
    event_queue->set_rpc_vector(d_rpc_vars, alias());
    work_call_count = 0;
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: It means exactly what it says. The compiler could not find a function to call that matches the parameters you passed. There is not enough information provided to know what the mismatch is.

Comment: Didn't the error message list the candidates as well ? Please include the complete error message, as well as the MRE already asked for.

Comment: My apologies.  I will place more context in a few minutes.

Comment: Your updates to the question did not help clarify it at all. You didn't add a minimal, reproducible example, so it's not possible to match the error message to your code, and hence identify the problem. Your answer thus also doesn't fit the question. At this point, it's probably best to delete this question, since it serves no purpose in its current state.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, I simply got away from the `std::vector<boost::any>` call and used the `std::vector<rpcbasic>`

Yes, I am using gr-eventstream and in my original post I show the line of code `void set_rpc_vector(std::vector<boost::any> &v, const std::string &alias);`

I am now using the std::vector line instead.

Comment: This answer doesn't really help anybody. You need to explain what `es_sink`, `gr_vector`, etc. are. I'm guessing you're using [gr-eventstream](https://github.com/osh/gr-eventstream)? There is no `std::vector<boost::any>` in your code, so it's not clear what change you had to make. Please provide the fixed code.